# Xamarin Forms Binding Label Text not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin.android

I know that this had been answered multiple times before, and I've followed every possible guide.
It doesn't work.

Here is my code:

XAML

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=StatusMessage, Mode=TwoWay}"
       Margin="10,0,10,5"
       VerticalOptions="End"/>
```

C#

```
    private string statusMessage;
    public string StatusMessage { 
        get { return statusMessage; }
        set
        {
            statusMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StatusMessage));
        }
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

The class extends `INotifyPropertyChanged` and to modify the label text I tried both
`StatusMessage = "Status: ...";`
and
`Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { StatusMessage = "Status: ...";});`.

Nothing works.

Any idea how to fix this mess?

### EDIT

Adding `BindingContext = this;` as suggested in the main helped.

Now it won't update the label from code called from a different thread, as follows

```
private void OnEnableUser(bool authenticated)
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
    {
        [...]
    } else
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            OnEnableUser(authenticated);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the DataContext in the code behind?

this.DataContext = classWithStatusMessage;

Comment: In the class init i set `BindingContext = this;`.
This kinda works when i set the text on `OnAppearing()`, but then it is not working anymore. I'm going to edit my question to point out one thing i missed.

Comment: My bad. I was overwriting the label somewhere else.